# angularjs xeditable number but source is string formatted

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

I am using `xeditable` to edit data inline. Now I want to edit a numeric field, but the source data contains the number as string formatted. So I get the error `ngModel:numFmt`. How can I convert a string formatted number (example: `0.3`) into a numeric for `xeditable`?

I tried with the `string-to-number` directive, but it seems, that `xeditable` did not recognize it:

```
        <td>
            <span data-editable-number="row.factor" 
                data-ng-model="row.factor"
                data-e-name="factor" 
                onbeforesave="validateRow(data, row.id)"
                onaftersave="save(row)" 
                data-e-required
                string-to-number="string-to-number"
            >
                {{row.factor}}

            </span>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You can create a filter to convert String to Integer</del>

```
app.filter('num', function(){
    return function(input) {
        return parseInt(input, 10);
    };
});
```

<del>and use it like this</del>

<del>editable-number="row.factor | num "</del>

<del>Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kwN1pJxMA9Mfzi22hBVC?p=preview)</del>

The previous didn't work updating the model, better way to achieve this is to transform the data beforehand.

e.g

```
var rows = [{factor:"1"}, {factor: "4"}, {factor: "9"}];
var tranformed_rows  = rows.map(function(row) {

   row.factor = parseInt(row.factor);
   return row;
});
```

and then use `tranformed_rows` in your view.

Comment: Hmm..now number is shown, but I cannot save the values. Error: k.assign is not a function

Comment: yeah I know thats why I say  "The previous didn't work updating the model, better way to achieve this is to transform the data beforehand." Did you try it?

Comment: This works for me and it seems the best way to avoid a ngModel:numFmt error. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! you have to remember though to change it back to string after done editing